# Angular 8 Routing a component between header and footer is not shown with no errors at the console

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular8

I am having a problem with angular routing.

At the `app.component.html` we have:

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

And the `app-routing.module.ts` is like:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule'},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

At the `app.module.ts` I've imported the `LayoutModule`.

Now at the layout module, we have 2 components which are `<footer>` and `<header>` displayed at the `layout.component.html`:

```
<div id="theme_id">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

I need to display the `router outlet` between them as the following:

```
<div id="theme_id">
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <app-footer></app-footer>
</div>
```

So at the `layout-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LayoutComponent },
  { path: 'query', loadChildren: './query-offers/query-offers.module#QueryOffersModule' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

So when the user clicks to go the query component, I need it to be shown between the header and footer.

The problem is that the `query` component is being shown alone like the following:

[image]

The image above shows that the routing is not working properly.

Comment: Your query route needs to be a child of the empty path route displaying the LayoutComponent, otherwise, why would the layout component be displayed? Note that you're using a deprecated way of defining lazy loaded routes. I also think you're abusing lazy routes. Why is the layout loaded lazily?

Comment: The syntax of loading modules lazily has changed in `Angular 8`. Check the angular docs.

Comment: Please, make a StackBlitz sample

Comment: @JBNizet can you post a detailed answer about how am I using a deprecated way. This is my first angular project since 5 months, so lots of things has been changed.

Comment: @chaitanya I am telling JB that I haven't worked on angular since 5 months so basically lots of things has been changed, if you can help me address this problem.

Comment: `loadChildren: ()=>import('./query-offers/query-offers.module').then(m=>m.QueryOffersModule) ` ? Thats the change ?

Comment: Okay, now I know the new way, but how should I correct the routing errors in my code @JBNizet

Comment: it didn't work. I will make a stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mistakes you made in the code which you provided and your explanation in the question

1. No need to include `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in both
   `app.component.html` and `layout-component.html`
2. No need to import `LayoutModule` in `AppModule` as you're lazily
   loading
3. `HeaderComponent` and `FooterComponent` are common in the entire
   project so adding only in `app.component.html` is enough
4. You need `QueryOffersModule` also to be `lazy-loading` then why you
   need to provide it as a children in `LayOutModule`. Instead of that
   you can provide it in `AppRoutingModule`

So your `AppRoutingModule` will look as follows

```
<!-- AppRoutingModule -->
const routes:Routes =[{
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'home'
  },{
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./layout/layout.module').then(
        m => m.LayoutModule
      )
  },{
    path: 'query',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./query-offers/query-offers.module').then(
        m => m.QueryOffersModule
      )
  }]
```

The following is your `app.component.html`

```
<!-- app.componet.html -->
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I assume there will be `query` button in `layout.component.html` or anywhere. On clicking that route to `query` which laods `QueryOffersModule`.